# Angularjs 1 - Show/update validation messages on submit click button only (does not change on user input)

Tags: angularjs, web

In Angularjs 1 there are many examples of validation on submit OR on user input.
In this project I need to update the validation messages on user clicks submit button only, i.e, the USER INPUT WILL NOT UPDATE THE VALIDATION MESSAGES (client spec).

Example: http://embed.plnkr.co/N0rRBS8AXU3jQJjQidIT/

Comment: Can you show a code example of how you are rendering your error messages? Are you using ng-message, ng-if, ...?

Comment: Already add an example. After the first submit it will be shown the valition messages.
If user updates the input value the error message will be updated (the two way binding in action). But for this spec I need to update on submit click button only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only need validation on the controller, so to turn off html validation you need novalidate like this in your html:

```
<form name="yourForm" ng-controller="YourController as yourCtrl" ng-submit="yourCtrl.yourmethod(data)" novalidate>
```

then you proceed to do your validations in your controller

Comment: If possible I would like to use the form validation structure of angular. As far as I understand your point of view, I will go implement the classic  form validation approach (and for this I'll need to create vars control for the errors, expose them on ng-if, etc. etc.).

Comment: When you change the value of some field associated with ng-model it verifies the type and other validations (like required) you have put and applies the ng-invalid class or ng-valid to that field. If all fields have ng-valid you form.$valid becomes true. All that happens before you click on the submit button.  If you need some additional validation from your server, you need to make a $http call and that'll be in your controller. I understood you wanted to enable the submit button click even if there are invalid fields If so you could test the ng-invalid class in your controller for each field

Comment: It seams that is the only way. I'll remove all the angular form validation approach and make everything on the controller with aditional vars to control the erros... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my option:

```js
(function(){
   'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('sample', []);
  
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sample">
   
   <form name="userRegister"  novalidation>
       
       <div ng-messages="userRegister.name.$error.required"
            ng-if="submitted ">
          <p ng-message="required">I need your name Sr</p>     
       </div>
     
       <input type="text" ng-required name="name" ng-model="user.name">
     
     
    <input value="Send" type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true"/>
  </form>
  
</div>
```